# Get user input to stop a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a way to stop a loop by getting user input without blocking the loop itself which works cross-platform.

Things I have tried:

- processes (closes stdin so I can't use `input()`)
- threads (can't kill a thread if the while loop terminates and I no longer need the `input()`)

```py
FLAG = False

def break_main_loop():  # how do I get this to execute?
  global FLAG
  user_in = input()
  if user_in == 'stop':
    FLAG = True
    return
  else:
    break_main_loop()


def stuff():
  pass


def main():
  # do stuff, e.g. getting other user input()
  while True:
    stuff()
    if FLAG:
      break

 return  # if I return here, I need to cancel break_main_loop's input()

main()
```

Comment: Why not use the KeyBoardInterrupt and catch it to terminate the while loop?

Comment: on LInux popular method is to use `Ctrl+C` to stop console program - and you can catch it with `KeyboardInterrupt`. If you don't like it then you will have to find `getchar()` or `getch()` which checks if there was pressed key without stoping code. If you create GUI program then it shouldn't be problem to catch key without blocking code.

Comment: [KBHit](https://github.com/gbarbon/python-asip/blob/master/python_asip_client/kbhit.py) - it checks if there is key in buffer without blocking code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work for you and simple to use. Replace main function with this

```
def main():
  # do stuff, e.g. getting other user input()
  try:
     while True:
        stuff()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print("Press 1 to quit")
 return  # if I return here, I need to cancel break_main_loop's input()

main()
```

Comment: It's not ideal to capture SIGINT over actually getting input from stdin but I don't really see a more correct answer right now

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
class new_game:
    
    start_game = True
    # end_game = False

    def break_main_loop(self):  # how do I get this to execute?
        print("game is ending!")
    

    def stuff(self):
        print("this is stuff happening....now...game is: ", self.start_game)
        
    def game_loop(self):
        user_in = int(input("enter '2' to end game or '1' to keep playing:" ))
       
        if user_in == 1:
       
        
            self.stuff()
            self.game_loop()
        else:
            return self.break_main_loop()
 
Test_game = new_game()

Test_game.game_loop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to answer your question. You see, once you are in the main-loop, you don't necessarily need to use a `FLAG` variable, rather, I'd suggest doing something like this :

```
def break_main_loop():  # how do I get this to execute?
  user_in = input()
  if user_in == 'stop': 
    return True # Returning integer 1 also works just fine
  else:
    return False # Returning integer 0 also works just fine


def stuff():
  pass


def main():
  # do stuff, e.g. getting other user input()
  while True:
    stuff()
    if break_main_loop(): # If the user inputs stop, the loop stops via the return statement automatically
      return

main()
```

If you wish to get out of the loop without returning anything else and keep the `main()` function running for doing stuff:

```
def break_main_loop():  # how do I get this to execute?
  user_in = input()
  if user_in == 'stop': 
    return True # Returning integer 1 also works just fine
  else:
    return False # Returning integer 0 also works just fine


def stuff():
  pass


def main():
  # do stuff, e.g. getting other user input()
  while True:
    stuff()
    if break_main_loop(): 
      break
  #continue doing stuff

main()
```

Now, there's a better way to break out of the loop without using the helper function `break_main_loop()`, and that's done like so:

```
def stuff():
  pass


def main():
  # do stuff, e.g. getting other user input()
  while True:
    stuff()
    if str(input("Do you wish to continue:[y/n]")) == 'n': 
      break
  #continue doing stuff

main()
```

This lets you get rid of the helper function completely.

I hope this answer was helpful. :D

Comment: I think my question could have been better worded. I don't want to have to wait for user input after every loop, I just wanted it to break the loop in the case that the user did desire it.